# Is "git add" the only operation to bring the file into staging area?

Tags: git

[image]

I am a newbie of `git`. After studying for a while, I have the following doubt: Is `git add` the only operation to bring the file into staging area while `git commit` the only operation to bring the file into revision history? If not, is there any other commands can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can also use `git commit -a` to add *all* previously added files into staging and then commit them in one go.

For example:

```
git commit -am "updated CSS"
```

Comment: And you can use `git commit` to perform the same action on a *single* file (`git commit -m "made some changes" myfile`) or list of files.